# Why am I getting an error before configuring a device in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2015, driver

I want to deploy my driver for testing. I have provisioned my target computer for testing (although this shouldn't matter because I am not even at that step yet). On my host computer I open Visual Studio and go to

**Driver** > **Test** > **Configure Devices**

and immediately an error window saying:

[image]

> Inappropriate request for export from part that belongs to another sharing boundary.

This looks like a bug in my Visual Studio (I have just recently updated to VS Update 1).

I am going to uninstall and reinstall since I have already tried repair. Any other ideas?

**UPDATE:** Uninstall and Reinstall didn't work. The bug is documented on Microsoft Connect: [Fails to load Configure Devices *(Closed)*](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2080376/fails-to-load-configure-devices)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was successfully able to configure and provision a new device using the following method:

1. Project properties
2. Debugging
3. Remote Computer Name, drop down and select Configure...
   [image]
4. Successfully shows the device configuration wizard, and was able to provision the target computer.

Was then able to select the target in Driver Install - Deployment, however I get the following error when selecting "Deploy". This could be related to my project tho, please let me know if you also see this.

```
Please select a valid target machine for deployment from the project property page
```

**UPDATE:** the above error may have simply been that I had the wrong configuration selected when hitting Deploy.

Comment: Yes I found that too but also that Visual Studio will still crash-out in some of the other places. For example clicking the ellipsis in the Driver Install properties of a KMDF driver (the bit where you now choose install or fast re-install). But it seems to work enough to get something deployed. It's good that you took time to document this.

Comment: For me, the dropdown menu under "Debugger to launch" in project->properties->debugging does not have the kernel debugger as an option, even though it does show up under debug->attach to process.  I have installed the WDK according to the instructions on MSDN, what else am I missing?

Comment: @Justin Stenning I get the same error as you `Please select a valid target machine for deployment from the project property page`. Were you able to solve this problem ? Thanks

Comment: @lads sorry I can't remember, but I had selected the wrong configuration, perhaps I had setup the debugging for one configuration and then was trying to deploy with another? Not sure sorry - it was a while ago now...

Answer (score 6):

I just applied Update 1 to VS2015 Pro and am now getting the exact same error.  It happens regardless of whether I make a new project or use my old 2015 Project. Looks like it's a bug in the update.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall didn't work either. I have submitted a bug request to Microsoft

Comment: Same here. Two VMs both upgraded. One with VS 2015 Enterprise upgraded to Update 1 worked fine, the one with Community Edition failed. Very annoying it seems not all editions and upgrade paths were properly tested. This is sad like the July 29th RTM build tools update one week later. The only true fix for that was a totally clean install of the OS :-(

Comment: @CodeChief Also I've been waiting for Update 1 since C drivers were not supported until last update. :(

Comment: @CodeChief for me VS 2015 Enterprise upgrade to Update 1 - experiencing the same issue so I don't think it is specific to the edition.

Comment: @JustinStenning yes after further testing (wasted time) I too found it's more random that that. Microsoft ignored the MS Connect issue, closed without comment as "External". Very disappointing.

Comment: @CodeChief It looks like a response got posted on that link to the bug along with an apology for the handling of the communication with regards to resolving the bug.

Comment: VS 2015 Update 2 CTP is out. I'm guessing that's like alpha or whatever? Not sure. Anyway. FYI.

Comment: The current WDK still breaks with Update 2 CTP.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a fix, but I went back to Visual Studio 2013, as it does not have this bug, and driver dev is working great.

Answer (score 0):

I had the message:

*Please select a valid target machine for deployment from the project property page*

I was using the wrong architecture in the configuration properties for the project.  My target test box is x64 and I had my configuration set to win32.  Changing this to x64 fixed the issue for me.

[image]