# Visual Studio 2015 is always crashing with KMDF/UMDF deployment

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, wdk, kmdf, umdf

My Visual Studio 2015 is always crashing when I'm trying to set the target device in `Project Properties -> Driver Install -> Deployment` part.

[image]

Here, if to try to configure device, the VS2015 is crashing always. This behavior is the same both for KMDF/UMDF types of project.

[image]

I've tried to reinstall WDK, but the final result is the same...
I can't even finish both basic tutorials for UMDF/KDMF projects at MSDN...

What have I do to fix this issue?

Comment: any further info from the eventlog?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander If I understood correctly, there are even 5 event-logs from that crash. They are: http://pastebin.com/WPkMvmeR , http://pastebin.com/dDwm6fgx , http://pastebin.com/pshshitz , http://pastebin.com/LmcPnC9W , http://pastebin.com/tJtymy2K

Comment: can you reproduce it on a 2nd conputer? there is a complete vs2015 install on win10 vitual machine  to download at msdn.

Comment: also pls try to start vs using Devenv.exe /SafeMode,

Comment: @FalcoAlexander VS in safe mode even doesn't allow me to view project properties. If I try to do it, then I've got the next error: http://oi63.tinypic.com/25spojm.jpg

About reproducing... I shall answer you later, just because it takes time :)

Comment: @FalcoAlexander have tried at another PC, the same result...

Comment: I can confirm/reproduce the error. You should report it to MS

Comment: This has been an issue since VS2013. I would recommend manual deployment.

Comment: please keep us updated

Comment: Not seeing this filed on Connect, I went ahead and filed a bug as I am also seeing this on two different machines: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2439262/configuring-deployment-device-can-crash-vs2015-with-ddk

Comment: This question is an indirect duplicate of <http://stackoverflow.com/q/34027555/2815044> as both problems have the same cause. The answer posted by [Justin Stenning](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34198399/2815044) should provide a feasible workaround (as it did for me).