# Red box when trying to configure Visual Studio remote debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging, device-driver

When trying to configure a machine for debugging in Visual Studio 2015<sup>1</sup>, there is a strange red box around the **Provision device and choose debugger settings** option:

[image]

I did not place that red box in the screenshot; it really is there in the Visual Studio 2015 user interface.

My questions are:

- What is this red box trying to tell me
- Why am i unable to add a new target device (i.e. **Next** and **Finish** are always disabled (no matter what display name i enter, or what radio button i check))
- How do i remotely debug a device driver?

### Background

Setting up kernel mode debugging in Visual Studio is pretty well documented on MSDN:

[Setting Up Kernel-Mode Debugging of a Virtual Machine in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj200334(v=vs.85).aspx)

There's only two problems:

> **Configuring the Host Computer**
>
> The host computer can be the same physical computer that is running the virtual machine, or it can be a separate computer.
>   1. On the host computer, in Visual Studio, on the **Driver** menu, choose **Test** > **Configure Computer**.

The first problem is that there is no **Configure Computer** option in the **Driver** > **Test** menu:

[image]

### The docs are just out of date

Problem 2. We assume the documentation is out of date, and that they actually mean **Driver** > **Test** > **Configure Devices**, that crashes:

[image]

This is a well-known regression in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1:

> [Microsoft Connect: Fails to load Configure Devices](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2080376/fails-to-load-configure-devices) *(Closed)*
>
> 1/12/2016 Gabriel [MSFT]
>
> I apologize for the delay in communication. In short, this bug has been fixed recently and changes should be reflected in a future update to Visual Studio 2015.

The issue was closed in January. Four months later Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 has been released, and it is still broken:

> 2/11/2016
>   VS2015 Update 2 CTP still breaks with WDK10 10.0.10586.0.
>
> 3/25/2016
>   Still broken.
>
> 4/9/2016
>   VS2015 Update 2 with latest WDK still broken.....

### Get to the config UI through another way

While one set of VS folks broke access to the **Device Configuration** UI through the documented way to reach it; there is still the undocumented way to access the **Device Configuration** UI. [Justin Stenning pointed it out right here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34198399/12597):

[image]

Which i am able to reach: it leads to the screenshot i showed at the top - a dialog that doesn't let me configure a device, and has a red box that's trying to tell me something:

[image]

What is this red box trying to tell me?
How do i configure a device for remote debugging?
How do i debug a device driver in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2?<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> Community Edition

Comment: It's time to rent a movie?

Comment: @spencer7593 How did you know that i just bought The Force Awakens Blu-Ray, and it refuses to play on my PS3, and i'm downloading the rip as we speak.

Comment: +10 (I'll delete my comment once your question gets more attention.) If you still can't get it to play, I can lend you the original version of that motion picture, A New Hope, which was released back in 1977. It's pretty much the same movie.

Comment: @spencer7593 I have the VHS, and the DVD, and the [ANHDE](http://www.denofgeek.us/movies/star-wars/246390/star-wars-fan-creates-despecialized-original-trilogy) of Episode IV. On, and my free digital download won't download (*Unexpected error*). I'm *hoping* i get an e-mail from Disney lawyers for torrenting it; i need someone to yell at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue: "red box" and spent a couple of hours searching for the answer online. Then realized that the "red box" is from another Dialog element, as you can see in the official documentation.

[image]

So the solution is to resize "Device Configuration" Dialog window.

Comment: Good god. If the reason i couldn't debug device drivers for 8 months is because the dialog needed to be re-sized: i am going to scream.